# How to create unmanaged c++ project in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unmanaged

If I select Win32 Project is it enough?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, creating Win32 Project is enough

- (MFC/ATL) Dynamic Library
- Win32 Console application

are also good options.

You can always make it mixed mode by enabling /clr support (later)